# In Objective-C,what is the naming convention around protocols and their implementation classes?

Tags: coding-standards, objective-c, conventions, protocol

Is there a naming convention for protocols and concrete implementations of them in Objective-C? Specifically regarding a protocol that's used as an abstract 'service' or 'manager' class declaration.

For example, in Java you might have an interface `SomeService` to describe some data service and call its implementing class `SomeServiceImpl` (or `ISomeService` and its implementing class `SomeService`).

If I have a protocol `@protocol SomeService <NSObject>`, is there a naming convention for the class that implements said protocol?
e.g. `@interface SomeServiceImpl : NSObject <SomeService>`

Comment: Read this question you will surely get your answer.
[Protocol Naming in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483813/protocol-naming-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

[Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) and [Objective-C style guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/objective-c-style-guide) is a great resource for answering any naming convention questions. My answer is as much as possible based off of this.

**Init Method**

The init method looks good.

```
- (id) initWithName:(NSString *) name;
```

**Class Method**

The class method looks good.

```
+ (NSString *) aliasForName:(NSString *) name
```

Class methods can also be used to instantiate an instance of an object. In this instance, Apple's API's generally have the method start with the name of the class like UIButton's buttonWithType: method that has the signature:

```
+ (id)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType
```

**Instance Methods**

Good resource for coding conventions for methods can be found under General Rules.

The following method should drop the `and`s:

```
- (void) methodWithApple:(NSString *) apple andOrange:(NSString *) orange andMango:(NSString *) mango  // BAD
```

Don’t use “and” to link keywords that are attributes of the receiver.

```
- (int)runModalForDirectory:(NSString *)path file:(NSString *) name types:(NSArray *)fileTypes; //RIGHT 

- (int)runModalForDirectory:(NSString *)path andFile:(NSString *)name andTypes:(NSArray *)fileTypes; //WRONG
```

The signature should look more like the following:

```
    - (void) methodWithApple:(NSString*)apple orange:(NSString*)orange
    mango:(NSString*)mango  // GOOD
```